# Is there a limit on shared documents on Google Docs?

Tags: file-sharing, google-workspace

I have an 800MB file that I need to share to multiple people. I'm guessing ~10,000 will download it.

I purchased extra space on Google Docs. Can Google Docs handle this or should I look into another service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's Google's response: [Google Docs size limits](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=37603).

As long as you upload the file as is (don't convert to Google format) you should be fine with a free account.

Comment: Sorry.. 800MB.. I would say my keyboard got in the way but I can't claim that excuse.

Comment: I was wondering what kind of messed-up, government secrets would make an 800GB document!  In that case, provided you upload it as is (don't convert to Google format), you'll be fine with a free account.  Answer updated...

Comment: I did work for government agency at one time with Top Secret clearance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent_%28protocol%29) as a mean for information dissemination for a file that big of a size to tens of thousands of people.

`800GB * 10000` is `8 petabytes` worth of bandwidth. BitTorrent's peer-to-peer technology will help to alleviate the **huge** cost of the bandwidth and storage needed.

**Edit:**

My suggestion remains the same for a 800MB file.

Comment: Sorry.. 800MB.. I would say my keyboard got in the way but I can't claim that excuse.